# How to extend MapActivity Code to track Location of Another Device on Basis of Device ID Or Login Credentials and GPS Location in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps, location

My MapActivity.java shows the location of my device along with the timestamp, I am creating app that shows lost or stolen phone's location and which has my app pre installed and logged in and successfully setup. So how do I use that device Phone ID, GPS Location and and its login credentials(mob no, email and password) to show its location on my Phone's Activity Map???

Please help me out with a solution.

My **MapActivity.java**

```
package com.skynet.fs5;

import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
 import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.maps.android.ui.IconGenerator;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

 public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
 LocationListener,
 GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
 GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

 private static final String TAG = "LocationActivity";
 private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 1; //1 minute
 private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute
 Button btnFusedLocation;
 TextView tvLocation;
 LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
 GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
 Location mCurrentLocation;
 String mLastUpdateTime;
 GoogleMap googleMap;

  private Toolbar mToolbar;

 protected void createLocationRequest() {
 mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
 mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
 mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
 mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 Log.d(TAG, "onCreate ...............................");
 //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
 if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
 finish();
 }
 createLocationRequest();
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
 .addApi(LocationServices.API)
 .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
 .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
 .build();
  assert getActionBar()!=null;
  mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    finish();
   }
  });
 setContentView(R.layout.settings);
 SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
 .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
 googleMap = fm.getMap();
 googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);



 }

 @Override
 public void onStart() {
 super.onStart();
 Log.d(TAG, "onStart fired ..............");
 mGoogleApiClient.connect();
 }

 @Override
 public void onStop() {
 super.onStop();
 Log.d(TAG, "onStop fired ..............");
 mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
 Log.d(TAG, "isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
 }

 private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
 int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
 if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
 return true;
 } else {
 GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
 return false;
 }
 }

 @Override
 public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
 Log.d(TAG, "onConnected - isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
 startLocationUpdates();
 }

 protected void startLocationUpdates() {
 PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
 mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
 Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
 }

 @Override
 public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

 }

 @Override
 public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
 Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed: " + connectionResult.toString());
 }

 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
 Log.d(TAG, "Firing onLocationChanged..............................................");
 mCurrentLocation = location;
 mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
 addMarker();
 }

 private void addMarker() {
 MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

 // following four lines requires 'Google Maps Android API Utility Library'
 // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/
 // I have used this to display the time as title for location markers
 // you can safely comment the following four lines but for this info
 IconGenerator iconFactory = new IconGenerator(this);
 iconFactory.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_PURPLE);
 options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon(mLastUpdateTime)));
 options.anchor(iconFactory.getAnchorU(), iconFactory.getAnchorV());

 LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
 options.position(currentLatLng);
 Marker mapMarker = googleMap.addMarker(options);
 long atTime = mCurrentLocation.getTime();
 mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date(atTime));
 mapMarker.setTitle(mLastUpdateTime);
 Log.d(TAG, "Marker added.............................");
 googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng,
 13));
 Log.d(TAG, "Zoom done.............................");
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
 super.onPause();
 stopLocationUpdates();
 }

 protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
 LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
 mGoogleApiClient, this);
 Log.d(TAG, "Location update stopped .......................");
 }

 @Override
 public void onResume() {
 super.onResume();
 if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
 startLocationUpdates();
 Log.d(TAG, "Location update resumed .....................");
 }
 }
 }
```

and its **Layout** xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar" layout="@layout/toolbar_settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    tools:context="com.skynet.fs5.MapsActivity" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Final Output of Above Code**
[Output of above code with timestamp of last Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC6R6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, this is a very broad question so the most I can think to provide is a very broad answer.

Based on your code, I can see that you have already figured out how to acquire a user's location, so the first step has already been completed. The next steps required are as follows:

**1. Create A Credentials Database**

If you want to require a username and password, this information will need to be stored in a database. There is a substantial amount of information on Stack Overflow as well as the internet on how you can (securely) create such a database and how one would go about (securely) authenticating this data.

**2. Establish A Connection Between The Two Devices**

This can be achieved via numerous methods. One way could be to setup a socket to transmit data to the receiving device, which would entail the receiving device to  be listening for the incoming connection. This would allow you to propagate data (such as the location, for instance) from one device to another. If this solution suits your needs, I urge you to read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/java/net/Socket.html) on Sockets in Android for further information.

Comment: Thanks for taking interest. regarding the database, i think an online database should be used rather than an SQLite, as far as i understand that if I m fetching the Credentials or its Unique ID(of stolen phone), the relevant DB should be on such a platform wherein I can Access it anytime.  but as Parse has shut down its service, Can you suggest me any Easy to maintain Server BAAS or any PHP-MySql Server so that I can fetch the DB anytime. and I tried creating DB on [link] (http://hostinger.in) for Login/Signup, but there is some problem with Loggin in, whereas the Signup successful.